# Hiding text on small viewports

Tags: html, css

I have tried to use media queries and display: none in my CSS, but it does not hide the text on a smaller screen. Please help

HTML code:

```css
@media all and (max-width: 600px) {
  header h1 {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<header class="word">
  <h1> MY <span> WEBSITE </span> </h1>
</header>
```

Comment: Do you have test your code? it is already working

Comment: Your code is working as expected, what is the problem?

Comment: It does not work on my end T.T

Comment: Did you included meta tag for viewport `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` inside head?

Answer (score 2):

You can also try below code:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  header h1 {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<header class="word">
  <h1> MY <span> WEBSITE </span> </h1>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be working. I haven't seen your code so it's a shot in the dark but did you add this in head tag?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

This gives the browser instructions on how to control the page's dimensions and scaling.